# Как правильно реализовать алгоритм генерации специальной последовательности чисел?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Дано: `k (1 <= k <= 10000)` - количество различных элементов (чисел) в будущей последовательности, и `n1, ... nk` чисел, где `ni (1 <= i <= k)` количество повторений числа `i`.

Необходимо сгенерировать последовательность в котором любые два подряд идущих числа не равны друг другу максимально возможное число раз.

Пример 1:

```
k=3, 
n1 = 1,
n2 = 2, n3 = 3  ---> 3 1 2 3 2 3
```

Пример 2:

```
k=3, 
n1 = 1, n2 = 2, n3 = 5  ---> 3 1 3 2 3 2 3 3
```

Пример 3:

```
k=3, 
n1 = 5, n2 = 8, n3 = 10  ---> 1 3 2 3 1 3 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3
```

Ответов может быть несколько для каждого примера - нужно сгенерировать любой из правильных.

Какие есть алгоритмы для подобной задачи?

Answer (score 4):

По идее, вам надо сделать вот что: завести счётчики того, сколько осталось каждого из чисел. На каждом шаге выдавайте то число, для которого счётчик имеет наибольшее значение из чисел, не равных последнему. Если таких чисел несколько, любое из них. Например, если осталось 5 единиц, 5 двоек, 1 тройка, и 2 четвёрки и последняя была единица, то выдавать двойку, а если последняя тройка, то единицу или двойку (например, можно брать меньшее, разницы нет).

Алгоритм старается «выровнять» количества разных чисел.

Оптимальность алгоритма доказать сходу не могу, но вроде бы он правильный.

Пример работы: (в наличии 10 единиц, 7 двоек, 4 тройки и 1 четвёрка)

```
+++++++++o    +++++++++   ++++++++o   ++++++++   +++++++o    +++++++
+++++++    -> ++++++o  -> ++++++   -> +++++o  -> +++++    -> ++++o  ->
++++          ++++        ++++        ++++       ++++        ++++
+             +           +           +          +           +

   ++++++o    ++++++   +++++o   +++++    ++++o   ++++   +++o   +++   ++o
-> ++++    -> +++o  -> +++   -> +++   -> +++  -> ++o -> ++  -> ++ -> ++ ->
   ++++       ++++     ++++     +++o     +++     +++    +++    ++o   ++
   +          +        +        +        +       +      +      +     +

   ++    +o    +    o
-> +o -> +  -> + -> + -> o ->  ->  ->
   ++    ++    +o   +    +    o
   +     +     +    +    +    +   o
```

Это соответствует ряду 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4.

---

Набросал код (не проверял):

```
struct seq_value { int remaining_count; string value };

vector<seq_value> values;
// заполнить values
int last_idx = -1;

auto total_count = 0;
for (auto& s : values) total_count += s.remaining_count;

vector<string> result(total_count);
while (total_count-- > 0)
{
    int max_idx = -1;
    int max_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++)
    {
        if (i == last_idx) continue;
        if (values[i].remaining_count > max_count)
        {
            max_idx = i;
            max_count = values[i].remaining_count;
        }
    }
    result.push_back(values[max_idx].value);
    values[max_idx].remaining_count--;
    last_idx = max_idx;
}
```

(не вполне идиоматично с точки зрения современного C++)

Comment: да, ваш алгоритм более менее правдивый на первый взгляд, я тоже пытался с помощью счётчиков делать, выводить число с наибольшим значением счётчика, но вот момент "не равное последнему выведенному" упустил, попробую превратить ваши слова в код ))

Answer (score 1):

Храните для каждого числа время его последнего использования. При выборе очередного числа из оставшегося набора чисел выбирайте то, неиспользованное количество которого больше всех и время последнего использования которого меньше всех. При этом не забывайте о последнем использованном числе.

```
int time[10000], cnt[10000];
int n;

memset(time, 0, sizeof(time));
memset(cnt, 0, sizeof(cnt));

cin >> n;

int count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    cin >> cnt[i];
    count += cnt[i];
}

int lastUsed = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    int index = -1, maxCount = INT_MIN;
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j) {
        if (cnt[j] > 0 && (maxCount <= cnt[j] || index == lastUsed)) {
            if (index == -1 || time[index] >= time[j]) {
                index = j;
                maxCount = cnt[j];
            }               
        }
    }

    time[index]++;
    cnt[index]--;
    lastUsed = index;

    cout << index << " ";
}
```

Очевидно, что по сложности этот алгоритм не пройдет, но если хранить cnt как дерево, в вершине которого максимальный элемент, то можно попробовать уложиться в реальное время работы.

Comment: про время не понял честно говоря, и ваш код на этом примере `k=3 и n1=1, n2=3, n3=1` выдаёт `2 3 1 2 2` когда правильный ответ `2 1 2 3 2`